# .Net: FtpWebRequest "(503) Bad sequence of commands" error

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

On large files (~200+ MB), I get the 503 error when I read the stream.

```
ftp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(address.AbsoluteUri + @"/" + file.Name));
ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

response = (FtpWebResponse)ftp.GetResponse();
```

Any clues on what I'm doing wrong or a better practice for larger files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you receive the 503 after every attempt or only subsequent attempts?

Have you tried setting the disabling KeepAlive?

```
ftp.KeepAlive = false;
```

I would try a more rubust ftp client library, a basic free one can be at [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetftpclient/).

Comment: Never really found a good solution to my problem but the free one was a good recommendation.

Comment: i was getting the same exception then i set KeepAlive to false and turns out it is very slow, i have done some math on this. and `setting the KeepAlive flag to false will increase file transfer time by 43% on average`. which is not acceptable when you are transferring hundreds of files, so this is not really a solution rather a workaround, still searching for a solution though

Answer (score 4):

I'd concur that minimizing the number of NetworkCredential objects solves the problem.  I experienced this problem and created a single CredentialCache and added each credential once.  No more ftp errors.

Comment: after reducing the number the `NetworkCredentials` instances i ran a test to transfer 324 files and did not get this exception, so i would also concur that this is the real solution `not setting the KeepAlive=false`

Comment: @jaminator So were you originally creating 324 `NetworkCredentials` instances and getting this exception? You're saying `KeepAlive=False` is *not* the solution, right?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, several people seem to have noticed some success with using only one instance of a NetworkCredential object rather than using a new one for each FtpWebRequest. This worked for me, at least.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to not allowing time for the server to log out.  Use a try statement and when this error occurs, createa short time delay and have it start over.  This will allow the server to logout from the last rrequest.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the server (belonging to a client) had been changed to only accept TLS (SSL) requests.  They didn't tell us this of course and the 503 error message was not helpful!

So we needed to use `.EnableSsl` like this:

```
        var ftp = WebRequest.Create(uri) as FtpWebRequest;
        if (ftp != null) {
            ftp.EnableSsl = true; // <- the new bit
            ftp.Credentials = myCredentials;
            ftp.KeepAlive = false; // <- you may or may not want this
        }
        return ftp;
```

In order to ignore certificate errors, I also needed to add this:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

It's my understanding that this line has a global effect, so just need to call it when your application starts.

:o)